# NoReverseMatch using a path that has <str:pk>

Tags: django-views, django-templates, django-urls

How can i pass a urls path that has str:pk into my views and templates, I want to redirected a user to the viewPhoto template but when I click on read more, it's throw an error like this: Reverse for 'photo' not found. 'photo' is not a valid view function or pattern name. How can I pass this into my view and template ?

the urls:

```
path('view/<str:pk>/', views.viewPhoto, name='Photo'),
path('like/<str:pk>/', views.like, name='Photo'),
```

the views:

```
def like(request, pk):
    post = Photo.objects.get(pk=pk)
    liked = False
    like = Like.objects.filter(user=request.user, post=post)
    if like:
        like.delete()
    else:
        like = True
        Like.objects.create(user=request.user, post=post)
    resp = {
        'liked': liked
    }    
    response = json.dumps(resp)
    return redirect('photo')
    return HttpResponse(response, content_type = "application/json")
```

viewPhoto view:

```
def viewPhoto(request, pk):

    post = get_object_or_404(Photo, id=pk)

    photo = Photo.objects.get(id=pk)

    liked = [i for i in Photo.objects.all() if like.objects.filter(user= request.user, 
    post = i )]
    return render(request, 'photo.html', {'photo': photo, 'post': post, 'liked': liked})
```

this is how i pass my url in the home emplate:

```
<a href="{% url 'Photo' photo.id %}" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm m-1">Read 
More</a>
```

Comment: Make sure to make the url pk  an integer <int:pk> instead of string <str:pk> as i have done in my solution below .

Comment: I do it sir but the error is still appear

Comment: Can you please copy the whole exception for me to have a look?

Comment: Your question  addressed a NoReverseMatch  and not 'Function' object has no attribute 'object' so it's clearly not from the like and viewPhoto , please kindly take time to check other areas of your code.

Comment: The problem was mine so I fix it as you said, I didn't change my viewphoto template, I only change my home templates that redirect me to the viewphoto templates. But the sad thing was: The C.E.O deleted everything I do and suggested the one he watch in YouTube. Actually I hate watching video tutorial.   Thank you so much sir. You are my guru.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would do something like this to avoid url conflicts  :

```
path('view/<int:pk>/', views.viewPhoto, name='view_photo'),
path('like/<int:pk>/', views.like, name='user_likes'),

# this is for the viewPhoto
<a href="{% url 'view_photo' photo.id %}" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm m-1">Read 
More</a>

# Url for the like object, this would actaully help you avoid any form of url conflict 
<a href="{% url 'user_likes' photo.id %}" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm m-1">
```

Comment: 'Function' object has no attribute 'object' and it's highlight liked = [i for i in Photo.objects. all() if like.objects.filter(user=request.user, post = i )]

Comment: The error comes from viewphoto view

Comment: Actually the view looks okay there's nothing wrong with it ~~~ " liked = [i for i in Photo.objects.all() if like.objects.filter(user=request.user, post = i )] "  i just run the codes in my own console it works fine. maybe you are doing it another way, which would be better to add a detail exception for me to have a look.

Comment: And when you look in the viewPhoto there's no attribute of sort as "object" all is "objects" unless you are dealing with another view in question?  * Photo.objects.all() * like.objects.filter(user= request.user, 
    post = i )  * Photo.objects.get(id=pk)